# IronPython 'Type IEnumerable`1[TSource] contains generic parameters' when using Linq extensions on IEnumerable<T> structs

Tags: c#, ironpython

I'm trying to add Python scripting support to an existing C# library using IronPython. However, when trying to use Linq extension methods on one of my structs which is IEnumerable<T> I get the exception `` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource] contains generic parameters' `` whereas when I change the type to a class it works as expected.

Here is some distilled code that displays the same behaviour. As mentioned, changing A to a class resolves the issue, but doing so would result in unnecessary garbage generation in my actual project code so I'd prefer not to have to resort to this. I'm using IronPython 2.7.9 from Nuget.

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace IronPython279
{
    public struct A : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() => new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }).GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();

            var sourceCode = new StringBuilder();
            sourceCode.AppendLine("import clr");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"clr.AddReference(\"{nameof(System)}.Core\")");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"clr.AddReference(\"{nameof(IronPython279)}\")");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"import {nameof(System)}");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"import {nameof(IronPython279)}");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"from {nameof(IronPython279)} import {nameof(A)}");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"clr.ImportExtensions({nameof(System)}.{nameof(System.Linq)})");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"a = {nameof(A)}()");
            sourceCode.AppendLine($"b = a.{nameof(System.Linq.Enumerable.First)}()");
            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(sourceCode.ToString(), SourceCodeKind.Statements);
            source.Execute(scope);
        }
    }
}
```

What does this error mean (it states something that is true, but not why that is a problem) and are there any other workarounds besides changing to a class?

Comment: Side note: "_As mentioned, changing A to a class resolves the issue, but doing so would result in unnecessary garbage generation in my actual project code_" This argument is moot, since passing (or attempting to pass) a struct as an `IEnumerable<T>` would involve boxing anyway...

Comment: @elgonzo Whilst you make a valid point in this case, the real struct has other properties and may simply be created for those, meaning a lot of cases where boxing doesn't happen.